# About the integer solutions of $\ y^2=x^3+9$

Tags: number-theory

**Question** : Are
$$(x,y)=(-2,\pm1),(0,\pm3),(3,\pm6), (6,\pm15),(40,\pm253)$$
the only integer solutions of $\ y^2=x^3+9$ ?

**Motivation** : I've known that Euler proved that $(x,y)=(3,\pm5)$ are the only integer solutions of $y^2=x^3-2$. This got me interested in the equations $y^2=x^3+k$ where $k$ is an integer. In the $k=9$ case, I can neither find the other solutions nor prove that there is no other solution. Can anyone help?

Comment: Just curious, how did you find those integer solutions?

Comment: @imranfat It's *WolframAlpha* I guess...

Comment: Well, then I would suspect if Wolfram didn't give any more integer solutions, then.....

Comment: @imranfat The OP asked for a proof, we know that $(x,y)=(-2,\pm1),(0,\pm3),(3,\pm6), (6,\pm15),(40,\pm253)$ are the only integer solutions to $y^2=x^3+9$ but the OP wants to prove that.

Comment: Oh, I see. Yes, the question makes sense from that point of view. I didn't get that because he was already stating the solutions :)

Comment: There can be up to 12 integer solutions more (Mazur's Theorem), including the point at infinite (=neutral point of the Poincare's group of the elliptic curve)

Comment: Do you have a reference about Euler's proof ? Do you have the answer for $k < 9$ ?

Comment: @user10676: Well, a friend of mine taught me that Euler proved that. For $k\not = 9, $I've got some trivial solutions, but don't know how to prove that there is no other solutions.

Comment: These are the only integer solutions. Data for $y^2=x^3+k$ with $|k| < 10^4$ can be found at http://tnt.math.se.tmu.ac.jp/simath/MORDELL/. These results were proved using lower bounds for linear forms in elliptic logarithms (though the case $k=9$ can be treated more simply, by reducing to cubic Thue equations).

Comment: @MikeBennett: Thank you very much for great info. By the way, do you know any site which shows the proof?

Comment: There might not be an easy proof. The most straightforward that I know uses Skolem's method -- for this equation, this was done in a thesis of Hemer from 1952. Your equation reduces to solving $Aa^3-Bb^3=C$ for all triples $A, B, C$ with $ABC=6$. I don't know an elementary way to do this.

Comment: Like many "difficult" Mordell equations, the solution set for this one strongly suggests that a method analogous to Vieta-jumping should work. I just have never found how to modify the traditional [quadratic] method to handle the cubic case.